# How can $|2(v^2 - 1)| = 2(1-v^2)$?

Tags: calculus, determinant

I have an exercise where I am supposed to use the change of variables to solve an integral.

I am given that the area $D$ is bound by $y^2-x^2=1$, $y^2-x^2=4$, $x=-\frac{y}{2}$ and $x=\frac{y}{2}$.

Then it asks me to find $\iint_D \frac{y^2-x^2}{y^2} dA$.

Now I have set the variables as following:

$u=y^2-x^2$

$v=\frac{x}{y}$.

I have calculated the Jakobian determinant which results in

$2(v^2-1)$.

Now I have to solve

$du\ dv = |2(v^2-1)|\ dx\ dy$

and this is where I get stuck. The answersheet says its

$du\ dv = 2\ (1-v^2)\ dx\ dy$

but does not exaplin how? Would love if someone could help me out understanding this.

Comment: In $D$ we have $|x|\leq y/2$, which implies $|v|=x/y  \leq 1/2$ so that $|v^2-1|=1-v^2$.

Comment: @dromastyx Thanks, I've noticed now that I've missed something obvious really :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: $$2(v^2-1)=(-2)(1-v^2)$$ it works aslo here
$$\sqrt{(2(v^2-1))^2}=\sqrt{((-2)(1-v^2))^2}$$

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I think I need a break now, after overseeing something like that :P

Comment: have a nice break! a coffee?

Comment: Yeah, that should do, hehe. After all, I'm still on holiday, doing math, no pressure :)

Comment: Just curious. In what order should square root and power of be calculated? Doesn't power of 2 cancel out the square root, which leaves -2 outside the root?

Comment: no it is $$\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$$ for all real $x$

Comment: my Holidays are over and i'm doing also math

Comment: So $\sqrt{x^2}=x^{\frac{2}{2}} = x^1 = |x|$ for all real $x$ ?

Comment: no without $x^1$ it is $$\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$$

Comment: But isn't $\sqrt{x^2} = x^{\frac{2}{2}}$ ?

Comment: it is $$\sqrt{x^2}=|x|^{2/2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint 2: Does the formula work for $v = 0$? For $v = \frac{1}{2}?$ For $v = 1$? For $v = 2$?

Comment: Thanks for the hint :)